# what is the difference between org_id and organization_id in oracle apps?

Tags: oracle-apps

**org_id** is the ***unique id*** for the operating unit whereas organization _id is the ID for the Inventory Organization which is under an Operating Unit. what is an operating unit then. I went through many tutorials online could not able to understand. the solution I got is :

```
ORG_ID:
```

Unique ID for the Operating Unit.
Come under operating unit in Multiorg.
Used to distinguish the data of different business organizations.

```
ORGANIZATION_ID:
```

ID for the Inventory Organization which is under an Operating Unit.
Come under inventory organization.
Used to identify the items belongs to which inventory organization it has assigned.

and inventory organisations comes under operating units.I mean many inventory organisations can have one operating unit.am I correct???

Comment: Also note that one organization record can have multiple classifications at the same time, e.g. Operating Unit, Inventory Organization, HR Org, Business Group and others (see examples here: https://www.enginatics.com/reports/per-organizations/). Many customers set up different organization records for operating unit and inventory organizations (warehouses) to reduce confusion and to allow linking different warehouses to the same operating unit for example. And yes, many inventory orgs can be linked to one operating unit, the relation is in view org_organization_definitions

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Operating unit is based on a Region/Location. Multiple Inventory Organization can be assigned to a single Operating Unit. An operating unit is assigned to one General Ledger.

If the Company is registered in different countries, then the GL are different and so the operating unit should be different.

Table Names:
Operating Unit - HR_OPERATING_UNITS
Organization - HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS

You can read further about the same in the below link. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e13423/T443823T443826.htm

If you want to know how the columns are mapped to these tables, please check the table in the Oracle ETRM (http://etrm.oracle.com/). You will be able to find the foreign key information of the object.

[Select version and FND Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRxPL.png)

[Input your object name and submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnlgi.png)

[Select the object type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hW2v.png)

[Select the object name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOKgQ.png)

[Object's information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy9v5.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle EBS, all organizations, regardless of which type are stored in the same table hr_all_organization_units.
Depending on how they are used for the business, they are classified for example as inventory orgs, operating units, HR organizations etc..

You might find systems, where an inventory organization_id is the same as the operating unit org_id, which means that the organization record is both at the same time.

Have a look at the example data sheet of our [PER Organizations](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/per-organizations/) Blitz Report, which shows the different organization classifications in columns G to P (filter for OU or INV not null to only see operating units and inv orgs).

An Inventory Organization typically means a physical warehouse with items and stock, whereas an Operating Unit is just a logical concept to separate data access when working with modules such as AP, AR, ONT and others.

For financial reporting (e.g. to the tax authorities), the transactions done in operating units are transferred into a ledger, and there is a hierarchy: Ledger-> Operating Unit-> Inventory Organization as show in the [GL Ledgers and Organizations](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/gl-ledgers-and-organizations/) report.